# django 3.2 how to save multiple related model in a single model like inlineformset_factory using django-rest-framework?

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I would like to store multiple checklist that belongs to a single declaration using django rest framework but i dunno how to implement it thanks for the help.
Here are my models.

```
class Question(models.Model):
    id = models.BigAutoField(primary_key=True)
    question = models.CharField(max_length=50)

class Declaration(models.Model):
    id = models.BigAutoField(primary_key=True)
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, related_name='declarations', on_delete=models.CASCADE)

class Checklist(models.Model):
    id = models.BigAutoField(primary_key=True)
    declaration = models.ForeignKey(Declaration, related_name='checklist_declarations', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    question = models.ForeignKey(Question, related_name='checklist_questions', on_delete='models.CASCADE)
    is_yes = models.BooleanField()
```

Comment: Why not add a ManyToMany field to `Declaration` instead?

Comment: if i use ManyToMany would it be easier to implement with a serializer?

Comment: actually i cant use ManyToMany since each checklist has an answer column yes/no